# Add two custom buttons horizontally on a openlayers map

Tags: openlayers

I want add two additional buttons to a map with openlayers. With my code only the first button is displayed? What is wrong here?:

```
.olControlButton1ItemActive {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(add_blue.png);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}    
.olControlButton2ItemActive {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url(minus_blue.png);
        top: 18;
        right: 0;
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
    }


    .olControlPanel {
        border: 1px solid black;
        top: 70px;
        left: 12px;
        width: 18px;
        height: 36px;
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

....

```
map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);
var button1 = new OpenLayers.Control.Button ({displayClass: 'olControlButton1', trigger: button1Clicked, title: 'Button is to be clicked'});
var button2 = new OpenLayers.Control.Button ({displayClass: 'olControlButton2', trigger: button2Clicked, title: 'Button is to be clicked'});

panel = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel({defaultControl: button1});
panel.addControls([button1,button2]);
map.addControl (panel);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that when you add Controls to a Panel, only one of them is Active by default. So Button1 has the class `olControlButton1ItemActive` but the second Button has the class `olControlButton2ItemInactive`.

For your second button to work correctly you have to activate it, by adding this at the end of your code:

```
button2.activate()
```

Another option is to define the style for `olControlButton2ItemInactive`, but that way your button will be visible, but it'll not be enabled (So if you click it, it won't fire the event)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the width of .olControlPanel is only 18px, so there's place only for one button. Change it to 36px and the second button should display horisontally.

Comment: Hi, that is not the problem: Button2 is not rendered to the panel :-(

Comment: How do classes 'olControlButton1' and 'olControlButton2' look like?

Comment: Hi, the source above is everything at this time.

Comment: So how do you expect buttons to render if you specify classes that don't exist when you create buttons?